# My Tweak Isn't Executing

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos

#### EDIT:

- Running on an iPad Mini on iOS 8.1
- I tried a test project to hook `viewDidLoad` in the app to show a UIAlertView, but nothing happened. Does anyone have idea what could cause the tweak to compile but not run properly?

10 hours of debugging, I'm turning to SO.

There's obviously something wrong with this code, and I have no idea what could be causing it. I'm hooking the TestOut view in the ChineseSkill app, but when I get to the view it acts as if nothing changed from the original app.

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestOutViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
- (UIButton *)quitButton;
@end

%hook TestOutViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)view {
    %orig;

    UIButton *infiniteLivesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [infiniteLivesButton setTitle:@"Infinite Lives" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [infiniteLivesButton setFrame:CGRectMake(/*[self quitButton].frame.origin.x + [self quitButton].frame.size.width, [self quitButton].frame.origin.y + 20*/50, 50, 200, 50)];
    [infiniteLivesButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [infiniteLivesButton addTarget:self
        action:@selector(makeLivesInfinite:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *passTestButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [passTestButton setTitle:@"Skip Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [passTestButton setFrame:CGRectMake(infiniteLivesButton.frame.origin.x + infiniteLivesButton.frame.size.width + 10,
                                        infiniteLivesButton.frame.origin.y,
                                        150,
                                        50)];
    [passTestButton addTarget:self
        action:@selector(skipTest:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:passTestButton];
    [self.view addSubview:infiniteLivesButton];

    UIAlertView *successAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Infinite hearts for the rest of this test." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [successAlertView show];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(id)began withEvent:(id)event {
    UIAlertView *testView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Test Alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [testView show];
}

%new
- (void)makeLivesInfinite:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNNumberofLeftHearts:) withObject:@1000000];
    UIAlertView *successAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Infinite hearts for the rest of this test." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [successAlertView show];
}

%new
- (UIButton *)quitButton {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(quitButton));
}

%new
- (void)skipTest:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNTotalTest:) withObject:@1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(CheckOrContinueButtonClick:) withObject:NULL];
    [self performSelector:@selector(CheckOrContinueButtonClick:) withObject:NULL];
}

%end
```

There's no alert views, no added views, no nothing. Nearly anything will help.

Comment: What is TestOutViewController and what makes you think it exists?

Comment: It's a VC responsible for testing in the app. I'm quiet sure it exists (but I could be wrong, so please correct me if I am) because after using class-dump-z on the unencrypted app it was one of the resulting header files. http://pastebin.com/qSebYz9T

Comment: Just to be sure do you set your filters correctly (in your tweaks plist file)?

Comment: I didn't change anything. What _should_ it look like?

Comment: The plist should be set to your app, not SpringBoard

Comment: @twodayslate Post that as an answer and I'll mark it right. I've never done in-app modifications before so I'm pretty used to just leaving it as `com.apple.springboard`. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I didn't receive emails of your comment. I answered your question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have to set the right filters in your tweak's plist file. By default the plist file has a bundle identifier filter `com.apple.springboard`. You should change this to the bundle identifier of the app you want your code injected.

**Furthur information (Just a little):**

What is happening in behind? `MobileLoader` is responsible for patching your code into a program. These plist files tell MobileLoader to patch the code in which program(s), in which framework(s) or in which running process. So your process is the app and not `SpringBoard`. This [link](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Cydia_Substrate)
has good explanation about CydiaSubstrate (MobileSubstrate). You could also have a look at its documentation.